# Decision trees graph not working python 3.6 not saving

Tags: python

I am trying to print s decesion tree in python but for some reason i am getting an error message:

InvocationException: GraphViz's executables not found

```
import graphviz
tree = DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion='entropy',max_depth=18,random_state=0)
tree.fit(X_train, y_train)
dot_data = StringIO()
export_graphviz(tree,out_file = dot_data,filled=True,rounded=True,feature_names=X_train.columns.values.tolist(),class_names = ['0', '1'],special_characters=True)
graph = pydotplus.graph_from_dot_data(dot_data.getvalue())
graph.write_png("C:/Temp/Tree.png")
print('Visible tree plot saved as png.')
graph
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `graphviz` to PATH. Find your own version of this:

```
C:\Users\Env\Library\bin\graphviz
```

And add it to PATH.

Comment: Thanks! i get this now PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:/Users/naa56/.conda/envs/Python 3.6/Library/bin/graphviz'

Comment: Have you restarted your program?